# change the default font of UIFontTextStyleHeadline

Tags: objective-c, fonts, textkit

While using Interface builder & iOS7 UIFontTextStyleHeadline
I set my headline label to UIFontTextStyleHeadline

(I guess it can be done also with the following code:)

```
myHeadlineTextLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
```

**Q:**
this works well, yet I would like to have the same functionality only using **HelveticaNeue-Thin**

just as an example:

```
titleCustomLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:(**Dynamic font size as the user defined in his setting**)];
```

what would be an **elegant** way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIFont` has the fontSize property. You can make use of that.

```
titleCustomLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline].pointSize];
```

(don't use fontSize at the end)

Comment: excellent Suresh, thanks. - can you just fix the answer to pointSize to be super correct?